# Why can I not create a unique index with more than 3 columns in mySQL table?

Tags: mysql

What I want to realize is adding a unique index for every column in a table. But when I add more than 3 columns to the index, it will throw the error that

> Error: ER_TOO_LONG_KEY: Specified key was too long; max key length is 3072 bytes```.

I create my table through node.js, and the code is

```
db.query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tasks (name VARCHAR(255), id VARCHAR(255), `group` VARCHAR(255), owner VARCHAR(255), isComplete BOOL)")
```

and what I do is

```
db.query("ALTER TABLE tasks ADD UNIQUE INDEX (name, id, `group`, owner, isComplete)")
```

When I just add 3 columns, like:

```
db.query("ALTER TABLE `groups` ADD UNIQUE INDEX (id, name, owner)")
```

it is okay. So why does this happen?

Comment: Read the error message. The problem isn't the number of columns, the problem is the total length of the key with all those columns.

Comment: Remember that because of encoding, `VARCHAR(255)` can use up to 1020 bytes. So 3 columns of `VARCHAR(255)` use 3060 bytes. When you add the other 2 columns, the key is too long.

Comment: Check column's CHARACTER SET properties. For example, if it is UTF8MB4 then each char occupies 4 bytes, and each VARCHAR(255) needs 1021 or 1022 bytes. @Barmar - plus length byte + maybe null byte.

Comment: apart from suggestions about size and sums, checking almost entire row for uniqueness sounds crazy. you should better try other options -))

Comment: Thank you @Barmar and Akina, I soon realize that silly question. I will cut down some indexes. And thank you marmeladze, you give a hint that creates some unique key for each task.

Comment: @marmeladze I suspect he just wants a covering index of all columns, and uniqueness is not relevant. `UNIQUE` doesn't affect the problem.